# Filtering AWS CLI output for security groups that have specific port and IP ACLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq, jmespath

I'm having difficulty filtering AWS CLI describe-security-groups output

Goal: Find all SGs with ingress rules on port 22 with cidr 0.0.0.0/0

Amazons' own docs provide an example, but state there's a limitation with their query in that it will first filter the entire data set for port 22 then filter that entire data set for 0.0.0.0/0.  What this means is that SGs with the following rules will still trigger:

```
ingress 22 sg-12345678
ingress 443 0.0.0.0/0
```

This completely defeats the purpose of the filtering, and I'm not even sure why Amazon provides that example with a heading of "To describe security groups that have specific rules"

**Route 1: aws cli query first then jq**

This route is based off what I found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/971

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --output json --query 'SecurityGroups[*].[GroupName,GroupId,IpPermissions[?ToPort==`22`].[IpRanges[?CidrIp==`0.0.0.0/0`]]]'
```

Which provides a list of *all security groups*, but showing nested data for any SGs with 22 0.0.0.0/0 (and successfully ignoring any 0.0.0.0/0 ACLs for other ports)  In the output below, SG1 is what I'm interested, and SG2/SG3 needs to be filtered out.

```
[
    [
        "SG 1", 
        "sg-11111111", 
        [
            [
                [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "SG 2",
        "sg-22222222",
        [
            [
                []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "SG 3", 
        "sg-33333333", 
        []
    ]
]
```

This is a great first step as I've eliminated 0.0.0.0/0 ACLs that aren't associated with port 22.  But as I try to run jq to simply remove entries that have empty data sets, I'm having difficulty cause all the keys have been stripped.

- As I try to select deeper into the nested sections, I end up with errors like cannot iterate over null
- If I try to use contains, I just get back nothing, so I'm not even sure where I'm going wrong there

**Route 2: jq un-queried CLI output**

I've been unable to get away from the pitfall of the original AWS example by using jq from the start, where I can first query for all SGs that contain port 22, then query for any ACLs of 0.0.0.0/0, which of course gives me false positives.
Due to the stream nature of jq, I haven't figured out how to check condition A (port 22) then check condition B (0.0.0.0/0) only on items related to condition A.

Here's some sanitized raw CLI output of 2 SGs, again, I need to get the first one without triggering a false positive on the 2nd

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "SG 1", 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 22, 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ToPort": 22, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ], 
            "GroupName": "SG 1",
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678", 
            "OwnerId": "1234567890", 
            "GroupId": "sg-11111111"
        }, 
        {
            "Description": "SG 2", 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 22, 
                    "IpRanges": [], 
                    "ToPort": 22, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "1234567890", 
                            "GroupId": "sg-abcdefab"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 443, 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "ToPort": 443, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [], 
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ], 
            "GroupName": "SG 2", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678", 
            "OwnerId": "1234567890", 
            "GroupId": "sg-22222222"
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: another gotcha is whether port 22 is included in a port range, ie if the SG has port range of 21-80 then your query won't return this SG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use advanced *JMESPath* conditions. See if the below cli command satisfies what you are asking.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups \
    --filters "Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22" \
    --query 'SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?ToPort==`22` && contains(IpRanges[].CidrIp, `0.0.0.0/0`)]].{GroupId: GroupId, GroupName: GroupName}' \
    --output json \
    --region us-east-1
```

Comment: That looks like what I need.  Curious though the filters section seems redundant, any reason to simply not remove it as the query is what does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Ryan: Well I first wanted to reduce the output set to only security-groups which has `to-port` value `22` and then apply the query filters rather than applying query filters on the entire set from start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jq filter which will return only SecurityGroups with an IpPermission with FromPort=22 and an IpRange CidrIp of "0.0.0.0/0":

```
  .SecurityGroups[]
| select(.IpPermissions[] | .FromPort == 22 and .IpRanges[].CidrIp == "0.0.0.0/0")
```

Sample Run (assuming filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
{
  "Description": "SG 1",
  "IpPermissions": [
    {
      "PrefixListIds": [],
      "FromPort": 22,
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "ToPort": 22,
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
      "Ipv6Ranges": []
    }
  ],
  "GroupName": "SG 1",
  "VpcId": "vpc-12345678",
  "OwnerId": "1234567890",
  "GroupId": "sg-11111111"
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/GxsLPIvgX5)

Comment: I tried something along those lines, but obviously I did not achieve this since all I ever got was syntax errors.  Many thanks for this even though I'm not using this solution this time around, it'll likely come in handy at some point in the future

Answer (score 0):

**jq** solution to filter out *security groups* with empty nested data:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --output json --query 'SecurityGroups[*].[GroupName,GroupId,IpPermissions[?ToPort==`22`]
.[IpRanges[?CidrIp==`0.0.0.0/0`]]]' | jq 'map(select(.[2] | flatten | length > 0))'
```

The output:

```
[
  [
    "SG 1",
    "sg-11111111",
    [
      [
        [
          {
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: That solution is much shorter than I expected for Route 1.  While I'm not using this one, I may revisit this answer to figure out what exactly is being done here.